# Python Generating an IAM authentication token boto3.session

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I am trying to use the documentation on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Python.html.  Right now I am stuck at session = boto3.session(profile_name='RDSCreds'). What is profile_name and how do I find that in my RDS?

```
import sys
import boto3

ENDPOINT="mysqldb.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
PORT="3306"
USR="jane_doe"
REGION="us-east-1"
os.environ['LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN'] = '1'

#gets the credentials from .aws/credentials
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='RDSCreds')
client = session.client('rds')

token = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=ENDPOINT, Port=PORT, DBUsername=USR, Region=REGION)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> session = boto3.Session(profile_name='RDSCreds')

profile_name here means the name of the profile you have configured to use for your aws cli.

usually when you run `aws configure` it creates a default profile.But sometime users want to manage aws cli with another account credentials or amange request for another region so they configure separate profile. [docs for creating configuring multiple profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html)

```
aws configure --profile RDSCreds   #enter your access keys for this profile
```

in case if you think you have **already created** `RDSCreds profile` to check that profile `less ~/.aws/config`

the documentation which you have mentioned for rds using boto3 also says *"The code examples use profiles for shared credentials. For information about the specifying credentials, see [Credentials](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html) in the AWS SDK for Python (Boto3) documentation."*

Comment: Thank you, I had to back up and install the aws CLI, but once I did that I was good to go.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: glad to help :)